# Where are image streams stored in OpenShift?

Tags: image, openshift-origin

An image stream will be created after pulling an image (I don't know if it's everytime). The advantage of an image stream is the fact that it looks for updates or new versions of an image. But sometimes I don't want to use an image-stream so I also want do delete it when it already exists. 
I know this command:

```
oc get is -n projectname
```

It shows the image streams in a project. But I don't know where they are stored.

- Where are image streams physically stored in OpenShift (path)?

Comment: What version of Openshift are you using?

Comment: I'm using OpenShift Origin V3 on Centos7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metadata is stored in the etcd instance along with other cluster info.

Edit: if you want to delete an image stream, `oc delete is NAME` will remove it and make the images it references eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Hi, metadata is in etcd, that one is understandable. But where is the `actual images it references` located?